# Assembling all transcripts for an individual gene? (using single sequence to seed the assembly)

Tags: rna-seq, assembly, k-mer, stringtie, trinity

Let's say I have a candidate gene and I believe that in an individual sample, the genome sequence differs from the reference which then interferes with alignment.

Is there a way for me to do a "transcriptome assembly" with a specific read or sequence as a starting point? And only do the k-mer assembly from that single sequence?

I could probably code something myself but I feel like a tool to do this must already exist?

The goal here is to avoid the significant overhead of assembling a whole transcriptome when I'm only interested in one gene.

NOTE: In this case the data is RNA-seq

Comment: What did you mean by *genome sequence differs*? Does it differ because of SNV or indel, or because of different splicing?

Comment: Just assume it could be any one or combination of those features.

Answer (score 1):

In essence what you're looking for is targeted assembly. There aren't a lot of tools out there for that that I'm aware of, but on of them is [Mapsembler](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-13-48). The general idea is to input a seed region and then let the program perform iterative extension of it. That sort of strategy should largely match your needs.

Comment: Yeah this looks like exactly what I would be looking for! Will check it out and get back to you.